# Sending a json object in save method of mongopy

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo

I want to update a record in mongodb using save method.

I am using save method instead of update method because i want to remove the previous doc and replace it with a new one(but with same ObjectId).

I am getting the new object as a post request object.I also receive a emailid with which i will identify the record i want to update.

This code works:

```
db.doctors.save({"_id":ObjectId(doc_id),"name":"sharath","email":"abc@def.com"})
```

but i want something like this:

```
db.doctors.save({"_id":ObjectId(doc_id),request.get_json()})
```

But this isn't working.Is there any way i can send the json object into save method instead of specifying each field?

I am using mongodb database,pymongo in flask

---

This is how i got it working with the help of yogesh's answer:

```
newDoc  = request.get_json()
newDoc["_id"]=ObjectId(doc_id)
db.doctors.save(newDoc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing this on mongo shell, this will help to convert into in `pymongo` .

Let's consider your `request.get_json()` data looks like this :

`var jsonObj = {"name":"sharath","email":"abc@def.com"}`

so above `jsonObj` append `_id` as below :

`jsonObj._id = ObjectId(doc_id)`

and used this `jsonObj` in save like this :

`db.doctors.save(jsonObj)`

Hope this will help you :)